# SDL2 Invalid Renderer

Tags: sdl-2, truetype, renderer

I believe I have an SDL2 bug here and I wanted some verification. When I create a renderer it is invalid and I cannot initialize SDL_ttf because of this. Here is a quick demo program that exhibits the issue on my xubuntu 14.04 distribution. My graphics card is an NVIDIA GTX 550 Ti. Driver version 331.113 proprietary, tested.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
SDL_Window* _window;
SDL_Renderer* _renderer;

if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) != 0 ) {
    string error( SDL_GetError() );
    throw runtime_error( "SDL could not initialize! SDL Error: " + error );
}

_window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Conscious", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 500, 500, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
if( _window == NULL ) {
    string error( SDL_GetError() );
    throw runtime_error( "Window could not be created! SDL Error: " + error );
}

_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( _window , -1,
        SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC );
if( _renderer == NULL ) {
    string error( SDL_GetError() );
    throw runtime_error( "Renderer could not be created! SDL Error: " + error );
}

cout << SDL_GetError() << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Let me know what you think!

Thanks,
Jonathon

--EDIT--

If you take out SDL_image and SDL_ttf the renderer is still returned as invalid. 
Also this does not happen on windows with the same exact hardware. If this is not a bug would somebody please explain what could be wrong with such a simple example?

--EDIT EDIT--
This code prints out "Invalid renderer" on my system. If you have SDL2 please run it and let me know if you do too.

Comment: Why do you think your renderer is invalid? What does your code print? Please narrow down your question to specific error you get. Also if you feet it's necessary to put whole program here, then remove all unnecessary stuff and make it as mininal as possible for error reproduction.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin Because if you run the program it will crash saying the renderer is invalid. And that is a minimal program. It is intended to be copied and pasted and run. I have already verified that this does not happen on windows with the same exact code. I am very certain this is a bug.

Comment: Does `SDL_CreateRenderer` returns NULL or `Invalid renderer` error shows up later in usage?

Comment: Create a `sscce` ( http://sscce.org/ ) Edit your answer and remove as much unnecessary code as possible. Btw `TTF_Init() ` returns `0` on success, a better way to check for errors is `TTF_Init() != 0`

Comment: @PetrAbdulin SDL_CreateRenderer does not return NULL but if you call SDL_GetError() immediately after it reports that the renderer is invalid.

Comment: @olevegard Thanks for the advice. I will experiment with proper checking and create a sscce.

Comment: I tried you code. I'm not really sure why you get the error message. If you use `SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE` the code works. And even if you do use `SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED`, the renderer still is usable ( at least for me it was. ) I think that as long as the renderer is not `NULL`, it should be okay to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is indeed produces 'Invalid renderer' message, it isn't a problem because as `SDL_GetError` documentation states `You must check the return values of SDL function calls to determine when to appropriately call SDL_GetError().`, and SDL gave you no reason to look for error description in `GetError`.

Why it happens, by the way:

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x00007ffff7b00e90 in SDL_SetError_REAL () from /usr/lib64/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007ffff7b00e90 in SDL_SetError_REAL () from /usr/lib64/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff7b8f124 in SDL_GL_GetProcAddress_REAL () from /usr/lib64/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff7b8f80b in SDL_GL_GetAttribute_REAL () from /usr/lib64/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007ffff7b41bcf in GL_CreateRenderer () from /usr/lib64/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff7b3b66c in SDL_CreateRenderer_REAL () from /usr/lib64/libSDL2-2.0.so.0
#5  0x0000000000401383 in main ()
```

`GL_CreateRenderer` calls `SDL_GetAttribute` to get context version and such, which tries to load GL functions, which requires active renderer, but it isn't there yet. While not most eye-pleasant solution, it works well and it isn't a bug. Probable reason why you don't have it on windows is e.g. because it uses different renderer (d3d?).

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed up my error checking and am now getting an error in the ttf library. I will try to reproduce it in a small example and post it here. The Invalid renderer may not be related to this issue.

Comment: Your answer is correct. This is not a bug. Thank you again!