# "Invalid renderer" with SDL2 & OpenGL

Tags: c++11, opengl, sdl-2

I already used SDL2 before, and now I try to use it with openGL 2.1.
But when I try to create a renderer, I get "Invalid renderer".
For creating a renderer I already use the same line before for simple SDL2 project, but with openGL it appears to not work properly.
Does someone have an idea why ?
I tried to change the flags of CreateRenderer, and I have this error for all of them except "SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE", but with him I can't grab input properly, and when the mouse cursor goes out the Window I have this error : "Invalid window".

Here is my code :

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>

const int WIDTH = 500, HEIGHT = 500;

using namespace std;

SDL_Window* pWindow;
SDL_Renderer* pRenderer;
SDL_Event event;

void initOGL()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(70,(double)WIDTH/HEIGHT,1,1000);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}

void initSDL()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0)
    {
        cout << "Video init failed" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cout << "Video initialized" << endl;


    // Window creation
    pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Test OGL w/ SDL2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WIDTH, HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (!pWindow)
    {
        cout << "Window creation failed" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cout << "Window created" << endl;

    // Renderer creation
    pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(pWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (!pRenderer)
    {
        cout << "Renderer creation failed" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Renderer created" << endl;

    // OGL version
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);

    // OGL context
    SDL_GLContext contexteOGL = SDL_GL_CreateContext(pWindow);
    if (!contexteOGL)
    {
        cout << "Echec création du contexte" << endl;
    }
    cout << "Contexte créé" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    initSDL();
    initOGL();
    cout << "SDL_ERROR : " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to request a compatibility profile if you really need OpenGL 2.1. But it might not be supported on your platform. 2.1 is really old by now, you should use a more recent standard version >= 3.0

Comment: Mixing `SDL_CreateRenderer` and `SDL_GL_CreateContext` doesn't look like a good idea. At best, it will replace context with new one. If you're not using SDL2 rendering API, don't create renderer, just set up context and draw with GL.

Comment: Thanl you for your answers.
Jan Henke : Yes but I think my hardware doesn't support >= openGL plus I'm not familiar at all and I haven't time to restart and translate my code because it's for a project and I have only one month left :/
keltar : Yes but I think I need SDL for the textures isn't it ?

Comment: After several test, the Renderer seems to work. But I don't understand why I get this error message because I manage to draw with it. 
Any idea why ? 
Actually I guess my problem is kinda solved, but I'm curious to know why I get this error message whereas the renderer seems to work.

Comment: @JoutenJouJouHakujou no you don't need SDL_Renderer if you don't intend to use `SDL_RenderCopy`-kind of functions. Actually using SDL for window/context creation, input handling and threading while leaving all drawing to GL is a common practice, and it was so even before SDL2 (SDL <2 didn't have SDL_Renderer). Also your approach could backfire on e.g. windows, where default SDL_Renderer backend isn't GL but direct3d.

Comment: @keltar ok, but to if i load an image into a SDL_Surface i need it to create a SDL_Texture from the SDL_Surface isn't it ? Because I assume I can use SDL_Texture for create OGL textures (but actually I don't know how, if you do I'll be glad that you tell me how).
And as I said, it works even if it said "Invalid renderer" i can use RenderCopy and it works and I have no idea why o_o

Comment: @JoutenJouJouHakujou by manually generating GL texture and feeding `surface->pixels` into it, e.g. second post at https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/182865-Texture-on-SDL-OpenGL. "Invalid renderer" SDL error and `if(!pRenderer)` triggering are different things - I find it hard to believe you can still use NULL renderer, while "Invalid renderer" may be flagged during initialisation but isn't actally an error (picked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628174/sdl2-invalid-renderer from 'related questions', surprisingly it is exactly the question I thought of).

Comment: Yes my Renderer is not NULL, I thought that the error mean that the renderer isn't ok but it seems I was wrong, sorry for it.
And I managed to generate a texture, with creating a raw surface, drawing in it and using surface->pixels.
Thanke you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I could be a "built-in supported driver" problem if you compiled SDL from source in Linux for example.

Try to use "flags = 0" in SDL_CreateRenderer(pWindow, -1, 0);

Then test the actual selected renderer (this is in C):

```
SDL_RendererInfo ri;
SDL_GetRendererInfo(pRenderer, &ri);
int n = SDL_GetNumRenderDrivers();
printf("Rendering drivers (%i):", n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    SDL_RendererInfo info;
    SDL_GetRenderDriverInfo(i, &info);
    printf(" '%s'", info.name);
}
printf(", active = '%s'\n", ri.name);
```

Full source code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/josephpaul0/rockdodger-ce/src/2a8cfba934ed101ad76690e4f8b1cb360606fde6/src/rockdodger-ce.c?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#rockdodger-ce.c-1841)